# Jquery to be reloaded in update panel Not Working in asp.net 3 tier

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**Masterpage.master : at the End i had my jqueries as below**

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/iCheck/jquery.icheck.js"></script>
<script src="js/icheck-init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**For Partial page Update need to reload Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function pageLoad() {            
        $(function () {
            $(function () { // init
                $('.square-green input').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
                    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
                });
            });
             $("#rdbtn_img").iCheck('toggle', function () {
                $("#rdbtn_img").on('ifChecked', function (event) {
                    // shown
                });
                $("#rdbtn_img").on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
                    // hide                
                });
            }); 
        });
    }        
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl_logoupdate" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<input type="radio" id="rdbtn_img" name="demo-radio"></input>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Followed the link** [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/make-them-to-love-each-other-asp-net-ajax-updatepanels-amp-javascript-jquery-functions)

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: Its not working.. not reloaded ..

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery init functions are being hidden by the `pageLoad` function that you nested them in.

**change**

```
function pageLoad() {            
        $(function () {
            $(function () { // init
                $('.square-green input').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
                    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
                });
            });
             $("#rdbtn_img").iCheck('toggle', function () {
                $("#rdbtn_img").on('ifChecked', function (event) {
                    // shown
                });
                $("#rdbtn_img").on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
                    // hide                
                });
            }); 
        });
    }
```

**to**

```
$(function () { // init
    $('.square-green input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
        increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });
    $("#rdbtn_img").iCheck('toggle', function () {
        $("#rdbtn_img").on('ifChecked', function (event) {
             // shown
        });
        $("#rdbtn_img").on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
             // hide                
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! I tried the code as you listed above. but its not working when page partially updates in the form's one of the button's click event get fired . because of radio button is in update panel. I need to reload jquery ..   But couldnt find proper code to reload.